# Shading a cell based on the value of another in Excel so all cells to the right can be shaded based on its values

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

So I have a table that is set up with values going down on the left. For each of these values an important parameter is set by me and the rest of the cells to the right of it display statistics about what would happen if that row was set to that value.

For example if I set the leftmost value to a value greater than or equal to zero I would like the cells to the right of it to not have a clear color so I can read the resulting average that value will cause.

However if the value I put in the leftmost column is less than 0 then those statistics are not relevant I would love to be able to make everything to the right of that cell black as a result.

Is this possible in Excel?

Comment: Look up conditional formatting.  You can format the cells based on conditions either simple or complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the screenshot below.

- Select cells B2 to E7, making sure that B2 is the active cell
- Create a new conditional format with a rule that uses a formula
- use the formula

=$A1<0

- note the placement of the $ sign, just in front of the A, not the 1
- click the format button and select a black or gray font color and a black or gray fill color.
- close all dialogs.

[image]

If your data is in a different range, adjust the formula accordingly. Just make sure that you use the current row as a relative reference, without the $, and the column with the critical value as an absolute referenc, i.e. with the $ sign.

Does that help?